# \left and \right in different math modes?

Tags: math-mode

Can someone confirm that the following is illegal?

```
$\left($x$\right)$
```

That `\left` and `\right` pair can't be in separate math modes? I am getting an error.

I am confused since the following works:

```
$\langle$x$\rangle$
```

Thanks.

Comment: `$\left(\text{x}\right)$` will work.

Comment: There's no (good) reason for being confused about the second example: `\langle` and `\rangle` needn't come in pairs in the same math mode group (although they usually do). Think of `\lvert` and `\rvert`, `\lVert` and `\rVert`, or even just `(` and `)`, `[` and `]`, or `\{` and `\}`. What would *not* work is if you tried `$\left\langle$x$\right\rangle}$` in an attempt to enlarge the angle brackets.

Comment: Of course I don't know what formula you are trying to typeset, but **usually you'd use the same math mode for the entire formula `$\left(x\right)$`**. I would only jump in and out of math mode in very, very desperate circumstances.

Comment: Is this really a request for non-italic math symbols? `$\left(\mathrm{x}\right)$`.